# How can we pass a hidden parameter with a url to a jsp through a GWT java file?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to pass a hidden parameter with a url to a jsp through a GWT java file.is this possible?
If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

If a JSP file is hosting your GWT module, then no, it's too late to pass a parameter to that JSP.

If your GWT module is causing a JSP to be loaded, then yes, you can pass parameters.  When you create your request, add a post parameter.  If you're using a form, add a `Hidden` widget: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hidden.html